# allow WB from MEM stage to register file in 5 stage mips

Tags: mips, pipeline, forwarding

I’m trying to figure out what are the changes needed in the data-path and in the forwarding, hardware to allow WB for regular ALU instructions (add, sub, etc..) from the MEM instead of waiting for one more cycle like the regular 5 stage MIPS that has a Mux that chose between the MEM and the ALU result.
In this case the only instruction from WB we’ll be LW.
Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off forwarding from MEM to EX/ALU, which is a bolt on similar to forwarding from EX to EX.  (Also needed is forwarding from MEM to MEM for load followed by store with store value dependency.)

Otherwise if you really want to do register write back in the MEM stage for an ALU instruction, you'll have to dual port the register file write path — because you will sometimes have one instruction doing write back in MEM while the previous instruction is doing write back in WB — i.e. in the same clock cycle.  This a complexity that the original designers chose to avoid.  True, that the original design had dual ported for read and single ported for write, but now you need dual read, and dual write.  Not undo-able but the complexity adds up.

Still, if you don't have to implement the register file (i.e. just block diagram), then let's note that in the original design, there are two reg read 5-bit inputs and two 32-bit reg data outputs, and one 5-bit reg-write and one 32-bit write data inputs.

So, you'd add one more 5-bit reg write "2" and one more 32-bit write data "2" inputs to the registers.  Then wire the appropriate things to those new inputs, namely the output of the ALU output accepted by the MEM stage.